# How to run a MATLAB custom script with parameters in a workspace

Tags: bash, matlab, shell

I've a MATLAB function that perform some operations with variables previously loaded in the workspace. In example:

```
do_something(A, B, C, ...);
```

I run the function `n` times in MATLAB with different subsets of `A, B, C ...`. The output is save as `ASCII` for further processing with a C++ program.

I would like to time the whole process. So I thought to run the MATLAB function from the shell script, followed by the C++ programs. In example:

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "run matlabTest"; ./c++Test;
```

But I realized that the MATLAB function need some variables which are not previously loaded. So, my question is How to run a the MATLAB function with parameters which are in a workspace? . The workspace is saved in the same directory.

I'm working on Linux with MATLAB 7.9.0 (R2009b).

I've noticed (while reading/reviewing this question) that I can run linux commands in MATLAB using the `system` function. I've successfully done this but I would not stay with the doubt of how to do the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include multiple MATLAB commands within the quotes, separated by `;`. You could try

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "mydata = 1; run matlabTest"; ./c++Test;
```

for example. If you need many variables and this becomes lengthy or inconvenient, perhaps you could save the workspace variables off to a .mat file (say `mydata.mat`), and then load them in:

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "load mydata; run matlabTest"; ./c++Test;
```

PS You don't need `run`, just call `matlabTest` directly.

Answer (score 0):

For running matlab script (with parameters) in background on Ubuntu using nohup, the following command works for me:

```
nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nojvm -nodesktop -r "demCF datasetName 1 10 1000 0" 2>&1 > demCF_datasetName_100.out &
```